# How to expose mongodb publically using haproxy

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, haproxy

I have a Kubernetes cluster that is running a mongodb service running on port 27017. Additionally i have another haproxy service of type load balancer on k8. Now i want to expose mongodb publicly via this haproxy service.

**haproxy.cfg**

```
listen mongo
  bind *:27017
  mode tcp
  server prod-mongodb-svc prod-mongodb-svc.mongodb:27017
```

Whenever i try to connect i get the following error:

```
mongo --host mongo.<redacted>.com:27017
```

> 2020-07-30T20:03:29.689+0100 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect
> to server mongo.<redacted.com:27017, connection attempt failed:
> SocketException: Error connecting to mongo.<redacted.com:27017
> (:27017) :: caused by :: Connection timed out :
> connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17 @(connect):2:6
> 2020-07-30T20:03:29.693+0100 F  -        [main] exception: connect
> failed 2020-07-30T20:03:29.693+0100 E  -        [main] exiting with
> code 1

fyi i have setup A record that points `mongo.<redacted>.com` to the load balancer dns on aws

Ive checked the haproxy pod there are no logs, it seems like it simply isn't hitting haproxy

**haproxy.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: cgg-lb-service
  annotations:
    # Note that the backend talks over HTTP.
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:us-east-2:<redacted>f
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"
spec: 
  ports: 
  - port: 80
    name: http
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: "TCP"
  - port: 443
    name: https
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: "TCP"
  selector: 
    app: cgg-haproxy
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cgg-haproxy-deployment
  labels:
    app: cgg-haproxy
spec:
  replicas: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cgg-haproxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cgg-haproxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: cgg-haproxy
        image: <redacted>.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/haproxy:$TAG
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "50m"
          requests:
            cpu: "25m"
```

**Updated**

The above yml now includes:

```
  - port: 27017
    name: mongo
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: "TCP"
```

However after connecting i get a new error:

> 2020-07-30T21:48:52.581+0100 I  NETWORK  [js] DBClientConnection
> failed to receive message from mongo.redacted.com:27017 - ProtocolError:
> recv(): message msgLen 1347703880 is invalid. Min 16 Max: 48000000
> 2020-07-30T21:48:52.582+0100 E  QUERY    [js] Error: network error
> while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host
> 'mongo.redacted.com:27017'  : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17

Comment: How is the `mongo.<redacted>.com:27017` reachable from outsite the cluster? Which ingress mode do you use, what's your setup? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Comment: We have a haproxy service of Service.Type=LoadBalancer and we define config in haproxy to route to the service name in k8

Comment: Please can you pdate the question with the service yaml.

Comment: which service yml do you want to see?

Comment: @Aleksandar ive added the haproxy service yml

Comment: Oh i think i just spotted that i should update the yml to include port for 27017

Comment: after adding that i get a new error message check question

Comment: When the haproxy listen on 27017 then must the **targetPort** be `targetPort: 27017`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218941/discussion-between-aleksandar-and-kay).

Comment: hmm even after changing targetPort to 27017 i still get the same error message msgLen 1347703880 is invalid

Comment: I think you can also use Tcp-service using ingress ( not sure about AWS, but ingress-nginx does support it )